# Accessing variables from another Window Forms and pass it to other .exe Program:

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, inheritance, path

I don't have much knowledge in C# and had been learning for a while now. 
I would like to know if there's any other ways of accessing variables from another **Form** in other **.exe program**.

Before you jump to conclusion saying there's other forums related to the topic, yes I did some google search and found lots. But I couldn't find one is close to what I'm seeking for, or maybe I have't found yet. So I decided to post here to see if there's any help I can get while I'm still searching for related solutions.

Here's a brief summary of what I'm trying to do.

1. The user will input a .csv file containing data, the path of the file will be stored in a string variable **FilePath** when the browse button is clicked.
2. In another software program(**.exe program**) using C# as well, I'm trying to access the variable **FilePath** and use it in the **.exe program**.

*In short, I'm trying to access and pass the data obtained in **Window Form**  and use/pass it to **.exe program** for other purpose.

In the Window Forms, the string file path is stored in **FilePath**. 
So the file path is something like *"C:\Users\Students\Downloads\Project.csv"*.

The image below illustrate the UI designed in the Form.

[image]

```
//Window Form Codes
private string filePath; 

        public string FilePath //<======= stored here
        {
            get { return filePath; }   // get method
            set { filePath = value; }  // set method
        }

//string filePath;
private void Browse_folder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog get_file_path = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (get_file_path.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Get the path of specified file
                    FilePath = get_file_path.FileName;
                    file_loc_text.Text = string.Format("{0}", filePath);                    
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I'm trying to access **FilePath** from the Form and copy the string file path into a class which inherit from another **.exe Program** which use C# language as well.

```
//.exe Program Codes
class BrowseFolderTestStep : ABC //<=== ABC is from another .exe program
    {
         Form f = new Form();
         public override void Run()
      {
         StreamReader pathIn = File.OpenText(f.FilePath);
         pathIn.Close();
      }

    }
```

From the Watch list, I'am able to observe the string file path assgined to **FilePath**.
When trying to access **FilePath** in **.exe Program**, I get a **"null value"** for FilePath, the string file path is not passed over causing the program to crash. One of the solutions I could think of is to save the string file path obtained from **Window Form** as text file, csv file, etc, and access the file path from the file in **.exe program**. I would like to know if there are any other ways of accessing the **FilePath** so I don't have to get from text file. I'm not sure whether I could access if it's stored in the memory stream.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Look up "c# inter process communication", you probably want to use a pipe to write data in one, and read data from in the other program.

Comment: @Longoon12000 Sure, I will look it up, thanks!

Comment: See the [NamedPipeClientStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream). Extremely simple to setup (correctly), quite efficient and provides asynchronous methods. If you have class objects that hold the data, use the `XmlSerializer` class to serialize the class object(s) (not a BinaryFormatter), save the stream to a MemoryStream and `.WriteAsync()` the `[MemoryStream].ToArray()` content. You can also pass a CancellationToken, if needed in your context. On the receiver side, just deserialize the Stream. In and Out streams can be used concurrently.

Comment: See also: [How to: Use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication).

Comment: All right. If you hit a snag, let me know.